# Please translate the chinese word

Tags: translation

I am reading a construction plan from a Chinese contractor. The following word was not translated to English and I cannot understand it. I cannot copy it also because it was saved as image.

What does it say? Thank you. I found this in the electrical equipment schedule.

[image]

another one is below: Look like the one says "phase" (electrical term). Am I right?

[image]

Comment: 三相五线 three phase five wire (system)

Comment: 漏保 is short form of 漏电保护器, the leakage protector.

Comment: 天花检修口 ceiling access hole

Comment: 配电箱 distributor box

Comment: It said: "Please hire a translator."

Comment: @Kevman, that was kind of rude.

Comment: @JemEripol Rude but straightforward, right? You received a business plan and you are confused some Chinese word. You ask it because of profit, not love. I think you should ask the people aka translator who do it for profit - and they're also professional! So it seems that you're the rude one.

Comment: @Kevman, are you serious? Please don't make me laugh.

Comment: @Kevman, you might want to say that to all people in https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ for asking questions regarding their designs. If you dont want to give it for free, then do not answer! It is as simple as that.

Comment: Then sue google for providing it for free.

Comment: @JemEripol Do it in Stakoverflow. 1. Post a programmer question like: "how to represent a integer in Golang, I know how to do it in C++ tho. And BTW, it's my manger give me this task". Your question will literally got banned in no time.  It violates the code of community. I am still wonder why Admin still don't put your question on hold.

Comment: @JemEripol For the Google part. You clearly don't know how business run. You are paying for Google, in a indirect way - you use google for searching/YouTube. You see the Ad right? Do you really think Google is a charity/Non-profit? It's someone pay this service for you. Check the core definition of the "business company".  REVENUE/PROFIT!

Comment: @JemEripol The 2nd point reflects that you don't know business. If you value this plan well enough, you won't bother to learn Chinese yourself/hire a translator, I mean, attending the Chinese lecture or something like that, not post here are hoping someone could do it for free.

Comment: @JemEripol My point is: it's OK to ask question here, only if you show you're interested in those subject. From my point of view, you seem like those who "Wait, what are those ugly characters mean? Damn Chinese use English, I got to let someone translate it for me, damn, I don't want to pay for this one-time thing". You know what I'm saying? You are interested in this document, not the language/culture itself.

Comment: You are unbelievable, brother! Are there rules in this community that you can only post questions if you are INTERESTED in the Chinese Language? You talk too much about earning brother. Then come here and I will hire you to translate four phrases into English. How much will that cost me? I will pay you.. Did I give too much to translate? Is it a whole paragraph? If I can google it, then I will do it. But READ MY PROBLEM AGAIN! If the approach is wrong, you can flag the answers below then suggest the answer of Ali below? Right? Don't get ahead of yourself, brother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

天花 is short for 天花板 (ceiling)

檢 means 檢查 (inspect)

修 means 修理 (repair)

囗 (mouth) refers to 'opening'.  In construction term, it means "access panel"

天花檢修口 Means 'ceiling maintaiance access panel"

配電箱 means ' electricity distribution box'

漏保 is short for 漏電保險掣 (circuit breaker)

Comment: Wow, that was fast and complete. Thank you. I added something, can you please add?

Comment: Thank you so much. :) looks like the drawing is from the distribution box towards the distribution lines.

Answer (score 2):

天花 is short for 天花板(not 版)

Comparison table:

Simplified Chinese <----> Traditional Chinese

检<---->檢

电<---->電

保险<---->保險

Comment: ah, I made a typo.

Comment: No problems, sir. Thank you for replying and noting that. :)

Answer (score 1):

FYI, for your future translations, google translate allows you to draw characters with your mouse. You just have to copy the strokes even if you don't understand them.

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't know this is possible.